# Bringing symbology into ArcGIS Pro from ArcMap is bringing data with it?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I have tried bringing in symbology from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro, but when I did this, the data within the ArcMap document came along with it..I just want to bring symbology only! Otherwise I will need to create symbology that took quite a long time to create. Is it possible to JUST bring the symbology?

Comment: Create layer and bring lyr file into Pro. If even this is different, I am correct in keeping Pro on hold.

Answer (score 2):

You may add ArcMap styles (*.style) into Pro, see:

[Add a custom style to the project](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/connect-to-a-style.htm)